# Can VSCode display a binary file if there is an executable that will convert it to an equivalent text file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I sometimes use VSCode for a Delphi 7 project because I like VSCode's git functionality and for a few other reasons (superior string search, diff, etc).

Delphi 7 is a pain, and to get it to consistently compile I need to convert the dfm files to their binary version (all 2300 of them). This of course makes them unviewable in the diff viewer, or to just open the file?

Is there a setting where if I open that file, it will first pass it through the convert.exe (that's its actual name) util so that it can be viewed as a text? I understand that this might be read-only, which would be sufficient to my needs (though if on save it could just pass it back through, that'd be great too).

I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly to to search for on Google (the keywords seem too generic), but I can imagine some generalized functionality that would work for other environments beyond just Delphi/pascal.